# AWS Lambda is unable to find a SNS topic that clearly exists?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I create an SNS topic via the console. Then tried to call `list_subscriptions_by_topic` or `sns.publish` but they failed with this message:

```
    An error occurred (NotFound) when calling the Publish 
    operation: Topic does not exist: NotFoundException
```

The topic is accessible in the SNS console. Any idea why is can't be found?

This is my lambda code:

```py
    from __future__ import print_function
    
    import json
    import boto3
    import random
    
    
    print('Loading function')
    sns = boto3.client('sns')
    
    def lambda_handler(event, context):
        
        response = sns.publish(
            TopicArn='arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:031436316123:topicExists' 
            Message=json.dumps(newMsg),
            MessageAttributes={
                'event_type':{
                    'DataType':'String', 'StringValue':'something'
                    
                }
            }
        )
    
        return response
```

It is a Lambda trigger set on an SQS that is subscribed to `topicExists` SNS topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the SNS topic exists in the `us-west-2` region, but your SNS client is being created in the `us-east-1` region.

This line does not specify a region, so it is being created in `us-east-1` by default:

```
sns = boto3.client('sns')
```

You should replace it with:

```
sns = boto3.client('sns', region_name='us-west-2')
```

Comment: I tried this but still no dice....I was thinking maybe the access policy on the SNS was wrong but I included the appropriate permissions.... `{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": [
        "sns:Publish",
        "sns:ListSubscriptionsByTopic"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:2342342342:exists",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnEquals": {
          "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:234234234:function:*"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}`

Comment: ....okay so it turns out the topic ACTUALLY DOES NOT EXIST. I've mixed up a queue with the same name as a topic.